# how can a field in SQLite be set as not null?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table named `posts`, and i want some fields to be `not null`. so whenever there is no data, i want to produce a msg. How can i make the fields as `not null`?

Comment: So your table and fields already exist and you want to change it? You may have to drop and recreate the table. If you have data in the table, you can export it then -> `Drop->Re-create->Import`

Comment: ok. I use "rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text". I want the name to be not null, so how can i specify it.

Comment: Ah! That I'm not sure, I'm not a rails guy [wish I was! :( ]. Its possibly rails' active record supports this scenario on its own with scaffolding.

Comment: SQLite's `ALTER TABLE` support is very limited; you have to build a new table. If your existing table has data in it already that has the relevant fields non-null, copy the data to a temp table, drop the old table, make the new one, and copy the data back. Oh, and _do it within a single transaction for safety_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the table, just add "not null" after the data type for the column, e.g. "text not null". This will cause an exception to be thrown if you try to add a record with a null value for that column. You can add a catch/rescue in your rails application to catch this exception.

However, a better way would probably be to validate the data before you even try to insert into the database using an ActiveRecord callback...

Comment: ok. But i have already created a table, so is it possible to make changes to that table instead of creating it newly?

Comment: You can write a migration to remove a single column and re-add it with different constraints/default/etc. I'm not sure if there is a ruby method to alter a single column without removing it, but you could use raw sql in the following way:

execute "ALTER TABLE `posts` ALTER COLUMN `my_field` NOT NULL"

I haven't tried it myself, but it should do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. rb512 also gives an answer below to your question about changing the column. I didn't know that change_column existed. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

create a new migration to alter the table:

```
change_column :table_name, :field_name, :null => false
```